# Como calcular Cvar mensal no R?

Tags: r

Eu baixei as cotaçoes diarias do Ibovespa de 01-01-2012 a 31-12-2017 no R. Eu preciso calcular o CVaR mensal dessas cotações. Baixei o pacote Performaceanalytics, porém quando aplico ele, ele calcula o cvar das cotaçoes de todo o período. Existe algum codigo que aplico para especificar que quero o calculo mensal? Pensei em dividir os dados em colunas mensais e depois aplicar a formula do CVaR em cada coluna.

Alguem sabe o melhor jeito?

Comment: É melhor postar o código que usou. Assim como está é difícil de dizer como resolver o problema. Poste o código que usou tanto para baixar os dados como para calcular o CVaR, por favor.

Answer (score 3):

Creio que consegui fazer algo de semelhante ao que a pergunta pede.
Se não for o seguinte, talvez possa adaptar ao seu problema.

O truque está em dividir os dados por mês, utilizando para isso a função base `split` e a função `as.yearmon` do pacote `zoo`. Esse pacote também é usado para criar uma série temporal, a série `z`, só com duas colunas da base de dados `tickers`.

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(zoo)


ibvsp <- BatchGetSymbols('^BVSP', first.date = as.Date('2012-01-01'),
                                  last.date = as.Date('2017-12-31'))

tickers <- ibvsp$df.tickers[complete.cases(ibvsp$df.tickers), ]

z <- zoo(tickers[9:10], order.by = tickers[, 7])

z_month <- split(z, as.yearmon(index(z)))
cvar <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(z_month, CVaR)))
names(cvar) <- names(tickers[9:10])
head(cvar)
#         ret.adjusted.prices ret.closing.prices
#jan 2012         -0.01410941        -0.01410941
#fev 2012         -0.02108851        -0.02108851
#mar 2012         -0.02402775        -0.02402775
#abr 2012         -0.02146428        -0.02146428
#mai 2012         -0.03548744        -0.03548744
#jun 2012         -0.03252744        -0.03252744
```